# Spring WebFlux: Stream raw HTTP response string with headers for Mixed-Replace HTTP Response

Tags: spring-webflux

Using Spring WebFlux I would like to return Mixed-Replace HTTP Response that looks something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--icecream

--icecream
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: [length]

[data]

--icecream
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: [length]

[data]
```

where data is streamed from Flux (think `Flux.interval(1000).map(fetchImageFrame)`), but I can't find a way how to stream raw HTTP response data, most of the examples gives me access to HTTP body only, but not whole response where I can control HTTP headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping your `Flux` response in a `ResponseEntity` and setting the required headers on the `ResponseEntity`?

Something like:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/stream")
ResponseEntity<Flux<byte[]>> streamObjects() {
    Flux<byte[]> flux = Flux.fromStream(fetchImageFrame()).delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    HttpHeaders headers = HttpHeaders.writableHttpHeaders(HttpHeaders.EMPTY);
    headers.add("Content-Type", "multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--icecream");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(flux, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}

private Stream<byte[]> fetchImageFrame() {
    return List.of(
            load("image1.jpg"),
            load("image2.jpg"),
            load("image3.jpg"),
            load("image4.jpg")
    ).stream();
}

private byte[] load(String name) {
    try {
        byte[] raw = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(name));
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        String headers =
                "--icecream\r\n" +
                "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n" +
                "Content-Length: " + raw.length + "\r\n\r\n";
        bos.write(headers.getBytes());
        bos.write(raw);
        return bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like the kind of thing I need too...  Has it been verified to work, out of curiosity?  Despite setting the content type via the headers, I still get `Content-Type: application/json` back for the main part of the response, and then everything else appears to be converted to base64-encoded strings that include the boundary, the headers and the content!  I don't *think* I've done anything stupid!

Comment: Yes I verified the code above. You could post a new question showing your code. Someone might spot something in your code